# When did java files Compile in Eclipse ide ? and when is the .class file created in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

When we start writing code in .java files in Eclipse it immediately detect and shows error if there is any error in .java file that means while we are writing the code it is compiling that code at the same time and showing that compilation error.
The question is **Is eclipse compiling all the java code side by side and generates .class files at the time we are writing code in java files**. **If yes what happens when we use build option . It also compiles the .java file into .class files**.

Please Explain difference between the two conditions ?

Answer (score 1):

Java IDEs like Eclipse and IntelliJ do not need to compile code as you write it to flag errors.  If you think about it, this can never work.  How can you compile code to flag errors when the errors will make the compilation fail?

They can do it because of something called an abstract syntax tree.  All compilers use a lexer/parser to parse your code into tokens and arrange it into a data structure called an abstract syntax tree.  This AST knows about the grammar rules that define proper language constructs.  When you write something that runs afoul of the grammar rules the AST lets the IDE know.  The IDE can then highlight what you've done wrong and fix the problem before you try to compile.

You might say "That sounds a like compilation to me."  You are correct in the sense that the compiler has to create an AST, too.  The difference is that the IDE does not walk the AST and generate byte code; the compiler does.

Comment: Seconds sentence is too poethic.

Comment: Too poetic?  Why don't you give it a shot and we'll see how well you do.

Comment: All specification is relative and concrete, never mess with specifications.

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: I mean Eclipse and IntelliJ may compile code as you write sometime, in this case your answer is wrong. It depends on Damage, rbepair, and reconciler when to compile/hotswap. "never work" is absolute, nothing in nature is absolute and we are based on nature, dont you think?

Comment: I can tell you with good confidence that IntelliJ is not compiling code until I ask it to build.  My answer is correct.  How do I know?  Because IntelliJ is also dealing with all kinds of other things, like Spring configuration, that have nothing to do with compilation.  It's all in the AST.  That's the secret.  You are quite incorrect.

Comment: I can tell you with a little confidence that eclipse is doing the same way actually by "automatical incremenatal builds". But only Actually!

Comment: And i dislike IntelliJ because its context-suggestions are stupid but i wrote alot of plug-ins for IntellJ and the problem is the same: you have no garatuee when the class is built!

Comment: Sure I do: When I ask for it.  It's not a problem.  I don't think the context suggestions are stupid.  Best IDEs on the market, hands down.  (No, I don't work for JetBrains.  Just a happy customer.)

Comment: It does stupid suggestions in the past, did they correct them? I am downloading the community-edition and will switch from eclipse if they corrected them.

Comment: No stupid suggestions.  I've been using it for a decade.  I pay for my enterprise license every year and consider it money well spent.   Don't care what you use.

Comment: I created a class "Test", wrote the main-method and wrote `Test.` inside the class. After the `.` intellij gives me the suggestion to write "super" or "this" what is not available currently. This is stupid!

Comment: (sigh)  Whatever, dude.  Use what you want.  I don't care; I don't agree.

Comment: I don't believe in gods.  No jihad here.  I think your idea of stupid is wrongheaded, that's all.  Once again, I don't care what IDE you use.  I've made an informed choice that I'm happy with.

Comment: Please do not understand be wrong, whenever IntelliJ make suggestions as Eclipse do, I change to IntelliJ immediately because childrens are playing with a burning-glass in Eclipse too like this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479553 .

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is just an IDE, think about it as an editor. When it shows the errors is based in syntax, validations and build paths. When you "compile", Eclipse is using javac Compiler to generate .class files, which is different to just show you the errors when coding...

Here is a good explanation about Compilation:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Compilation

Answer (score 0):

> You have two modes of working: auto-build mode and manual build mode. By default, you are in auto-build mode and Eclipse takes care of compiling source files automatically. Builds occur automatically in the background every time you change files in the workspace (for example saving an editor). Auto-build is convenient because it means problems view, binaries, etc. are are up-to-date at all times. The downside is that in large workspaces auto-builds can be time-consuming if you are changing files in projects with lots of downstream dependent projects.

This is straight from [Eclipse Build Info](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/scoped_builds.html)

Though most of the times it will force you to do a manual build. Get used to it if you are going to stick with Eclipse.

Comment: This is not what IntelliJ is doing.  Another reason why it's far superior to Eclipse.

Comment: Yes Eclipse has auto-build mode and manual build mode and by default, it is  auto-build mode but even if we off the auto-build mode it's flag the error so this explanation does not seems correct  although eclipse  can do it abstract syntax tree which knows the grammar rules but then at compilation time compiler again has to create a separate AST, too .So eclipse has created a AST to flag errors prior to compilation when compiler again creates an AST. IF Yes what is the difference between the two AST.